# Math equations not rendered in Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, latex

In Mathematics.SE, equations are not properly typeset in the Android SE app. It shows raw Latex format.

Is there a solution to it?

Comment: Which parts are not showing properly? Title (by-design)? Post (bug)? Comment (by design, need to tap and select "Render MathJax")?